# Why not being greedy in triple dots?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not looking to brute this to work, with a workaround, I am interested in learning why it failed.

I am trying to match all occurrences of a comma or period NOT followed by a space.

I used this patt: `([.,]+)(?! )`
It should match only two cases in this string:

`This is a test... And,another test.`

It should match the `,` between `And` and `another` AND it should match the final period of the sentence. HOWEVER it is also matching the first two dots of the triple dots. `...`. Shouldn't the `+` make it greedy so it see the tripple dots is followed by a space and not match it?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The first 2 dots in `...` are not followed by a space. What do you expect? No match?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for such a fast reply. Yep it should not match it, it should see it as 3 dots followed by a space.

Comment: Regex prefers giving up a bit on greedyness (=backtracking) in order to be able to match at all.

Comment: [`([.,]+)(?![ .,])`](https://regex101.com/r/S0JQTF/2)

Comment: Pavneet and @OrEast yes this would work, but I'm very interested in why the greediness wasn't there to match the triple dots.

Comment: Thanks @Pavneet and OrEast your solution really helped!

Comment: @Noitidart i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex `([.,]+)(?! )` matches `..` in `...` because of backtracking. It happens when a regex may match a part of the string in different ways, and it is the case when you use quantifiers and lookarounds. Here, the engine matches `...` and checks if there is a space. There is a space after `...` in your string, thus, the match is failed, *but* the regex engine knows there is another possible way to match at the current location, and backtracks. It discards the final `.` from the match and checks if the second `.` in `...` is not followed with a space. It is not, there is a `.` after it. So, `..` are matched.

You can use an atomic group workaround here:

```
/(?=([.,]+))\1(?! )/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lYBmEC/1)

One or more dots or commas are captured inside a lookahead and then `\1` consumes the text. Since there is no backtracking possible into backreferences, the negative lookahead is checked after the last `.` or `,` and if there is a space, fail occurs and the preceding `.` or `,` are not checked.

A better way for a JS regex engine to match what you want is to include the `.` and `,` into the negative lookahead condition (see [Pavneet's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578598/why-not-being-greedy-in-triple-dots/42578677#comment72289775_42578598)):

```
/[.,]+(?![ .,])/g
         ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for this very much. The workaround is very cool. However Im very confused on why it wasn't greedy in my top question. Shouldn't [.]+ match contiguous dots?

Comment: I think Pavneet's solution is more JS regex friendly, I would post it, too, if I thought of it before. I will add an explanation why your regex did not work.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, I'm not looking to get it to work really, I just wanted to learn why it failed. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Noitidart: I added a step by step explanation of how your regex matched the 2 dots. Note it has little to do with greediness. It is just backtracking.

Comment: Ah thanks so much for adding @Pavneet's solution. I see his solution as not a brute force but a solution now. I was really having a hard time understanding the atomic group workaround. I will go learn more about the atomic group workaround now.